# Enviar mi búsqueda al frontend MERN

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

estoy realizando una búsqueda a través del método PUT una vez realizada quiero enviar una respuesta con el/los documentos obtenidos. Estoy usando controladores y pensé en agregar un controlador dentro de un controlador pero no me funciono.

//Envio el input desde el frontend

```
    const buscadorPro = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const res = await axios.put(`http://localhost:4000/api/query/${input}`,  {
            input
        });
        const data = res.data;
        console.log(data)
        getFindedData();

    }
```

//Lo recibo y lo manejo a través del controlador

```
    const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();

const {queryProducts } = require('../controllers/query.controller')

router.route('/')
    .get(queryProducts);

router.route('/:data')
    .put(queryProducts)

module.exports = router;
```

//

```
    const queryCtrl = {};

const busquedaExtrema = require('../models/productos')



queryCtrl.queryProducts = async (req, res) => {
    const { input } = req.body
    console.log(input)
    const busquedaTest = await busquedaExtrema.find(
        {
            "$or": [
                { Descr: { '$regex': input, '$options': 'i' } },
                { Codf: { '$regex': input, '$options': 'i' } }
            ]
        }).limit(20);
    res.json('Productos buscados');
    res.json(busquedaTest);
    queryCtrl.sendData = async (req, res) => {
        res.json(busquedaTest)
    }
}

module.exports = queryCtrl;
```

Alguien me podría guiar por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno he llegado a resolverlo, fue muy simple:

Para empezar en el router de query bastaba con el método PUT:

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();

const {queryProducts } = require('../controllers/query.controller')

router.route('/:data')
    .put(queryProducts) //un solo método ;)

module.exports = router;
```

Después y es aquí donde estaba la muy simple solución fue que cuando obtenía el resultado enviaba 'Productos buscados' así que en un momento de calma dije: pues si recibo este mensaje porque no lo cambio con los documentos obtenidos (que en mi server si obtenía) así que cambie el String con la constante que contenía la búsqueda, el controlador quedo tal que asi:

```
const queryCtrl = {};

const busquedaExtrema = require('../models/productos')



queryCtrl.queryProducts = async (req, res) => {
    const { input } = req.body
    console.log(input)
    const busquedaTest = await busquedaExtrema.find(
        {
            "$or": [
                { Descr: { '$regex': input, '$options': 'i' } },
                { Codf: { '$regex': input, '$options': 'i' } }
            ]
        }).limit(20);
    res.json(busquedaTest);
}

module.exports = queryCtrl;
```

Y bueno ya con los respuesta obtenida seguiré trabajando para ver que mas problemas me salen XD pero eso ya es otro tema, dejo esta respuestas por si a alguien le sirve, espero me haya sabido expresar para que me entiendan. Saludos. (Y)